# Multiplication rounding error

Tags: c++, rounding

```
double Money::rounding(int convert, Currency m)
{
    int tmp;
    if ( (convert % m) > (m / 2.0)) {
        tmp = convert + (m - (convert % m));
    } else {
        tmp = convert - (convert % m);
    }

    return convert / 100.0; // error happens here as well, 945 becomes 9.44
}

Money round(const Money target, Currency m)
{
    int tmp;
    double rounded;
    if (target.amount < 0) {
        tmp = -(target.amount * 100);
        rounded = -Money::rounding(tmp, m);

    } else {
        tmp = target.amount * 100;
        //error happens here
        std::cout << tmp << std::endl; // ouput 944, should be 945

        rounded = Money::rounding(tmp, m);
    }
    Money newM {0, 0};
    newM.setAmount(rounded);

    return newM;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Money a {9, 45}; // equal 9.45
    Money b = round(a, Currency::NICKLE); //argument a is 9.45

    cout << b << endl;

}
```

the function is to round the Money instance target to the nearest Currency, in this case, NICKLE.
since Money a is 9.45, it should round to 9.45. But there is a problem in the multiplication before the rounding, tmp = target.amount * 100; <-- becomes 944, but it should be 945, I understand that rounding errors happen sometime, but this is only multiplied by 100, why there is a rounding error?

Comment: This is yet another example of why you shouldn't use doubles to represent money.

Comment: `this is only multiplied by 100, why there is a rounding error` Because floating point numbers are represented in base 2, not base 10 (so therefore, 100 is not in any way special). 45/100 is not exactly representable in base 2 for the same reason 1/3 is not exactly representable in base 10, as a finite decimal fraction.

Comment: Are you sure that `target.amount` is definitely near `9.45`? Try putting this line in above the bit where you're seeing the problem: `std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << target.amount << std::endl;` (note that you may need to `#include <iomanip>` to get `std::setprecision`). (Note that it's impossible for it to be exactly 9.45 for the reasons Igor states.)

Answer (score 0):

In function `rounding` you define `tmp` but then don't use it.

Should be

```
return tmp / 100.0;
```